# How to get the value of the word in the file and store it in another file using python

Tags: python

file has the following line:

```
{"skipfilesyscheck" : 1, "component" : "Content Store", "script" : "tests/functional/cmeta_cache/test_cmetacache_ingest_kill_ddfs.py", "testname" : "CMetaCache_Ingest_kill_ddfs", "params" : " --ddrs=$DDRS --clients=$LOAD_CLIENT --log_level=DEBUG --config_file=/auto/tools/qa/shared/qa-branch/hashlist/cfg/juno/juno_cmeta_config.yaml -s", "numddr" : 1, "timeout" : 7200}
```

===========================================================================
I want only the value of component ie., Content Store and testname ie., CMetaCache_Ingest_kill_ddfs and store it in another file as below.

CMetaCache_Ingest_kill_ddfs Content Store

===========================================================================
If component word or testname word are not found in the file, then it should save the value of not found word as "NONE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json 

s = '''{"skipfilesyscheck" : 1, "component" : "Content Store", "script" : "tests/functional/cmeta_cache/test_cmetacache_ingest_kill_ddfs.py", "testname" : "CMetaCache_Ingest_kill_ddfs", "params" : " --ddrs=$DDRS --clients=$LOAD_CLIENT --log_level=DEBUG --config_file=/auto/tools/qa/shared/qa-branch/hashlist/cfg/juno/juno_cmeta_config.yaml -s", "numddr" : 1, "timeout" : 7200}
'''

s = json.loads(s)
print(s.get("component", "NONE"))
print(s.get("testname", "NONE"))
```

The line is a `json`. Use `json` module to load it. Then access it as a `dictionary`. The second parameter in the `.get()` is the default value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the data is stored in a json file? In any case, this code achieves what you're trying to do..

```
import json

# loads the file into a dictionary
with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
    file = json.load(f)

# tries to grab the values corresponding to the keys
# if not found then returns 'NONE'
output1 = file.get('testname', 'NONE') 
output2 = file.get('component', 'NONE')

# writes to a new file, joined by spaces
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(' '.join([output1, output2]))
```

output:

```
CMetaCache_Ingest_kill_ddfs Content Store
```

you could use this to loop through files, grab the two (or more) parts you want, and write them to a new file..could put it into a function if you want too